# Does changing an export from "no_root_squash" to "root_squash" require a remount on the client side?

Tags: mount, root, nfs, qnap

Situation: a QNAP NAS is serving several directories already and I want to change the settings away from `no_root_squash` to `root_squash`.

- Does performing this impact anything other than user permissions?
- Does a remount have to happen on the client side for this to take effect?

I would expect it to be transparent to the client, however I can't find an answer on google, not even anything broaching the topic.

Can anyone here tell me with certainty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `root_squash` option is done completely server-side, so you'd need a *re-export* operation server-side, but nothing client-side.

On the command line, the re-export would be simply `exportfs -r`; if you're doing the change through a GUI it will probably handle this for you.

If your client systems have processes accessing the NFS shares as root, those might start having problems as the files and directories they've already written (as user `root`) will suddenly become inaccessible, and any new files created by them after the change will be marked as owned by `nobody` (or `nfsnobody` in some distributions).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So if the directory is owned by a very specific user and the client side has access to only that user which they use to read and write, and the permissions are correct ( `u=rxw,g=rw,o=`) it should be fine, I suppose? My main concern was doing whatever command is needed to update squash server side and it not going through without extra steps on the client side, or that the client side would notice in some way other than the issue with the root user, as you described.

Comment: Yes, for any directory access that is already happening as any non-root (and non-nobody) user, applying the `root_squash` option should make no difference.